# Reshaping numpy array created using RasterToNumPyArray in ArcPy

Tags: arcgis-pro, numpy

I have generated a numpy array from an existing raster in ArcGIS using `RasterToNumPyArray`, but when it is imported the array shape is (bands,rows,columns) and I need to convert to (rows,columns,bands). However, I can't quite figure out how to do it.

Here is an example, with a toy raster with 5 bands and 10x10 cells:

```
old = np.arange(500).reshape(5,10,10)
new = old.reshape((10,10,5))
```

band1 would have values from 0:99 (old[0,:,:]. However, new[:,:,0] is not the same. I just can't quite figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It might not be the best way, but here is the example I came up with.

I used a different starting array.

```
a = np.repeat(1,25)
b = np.repeat(2,25)
c = np.arange(25)
arr = np.concatenate((a,b,c))
arr = arr.reshape(3,5,5)
arr = arr.reshape(3,25)
arr = arr.transpose()
```

Results in

```
array([[ 1,  2,  0],
       [ 1,  2,  1],
       [ 1,  2,  2],
       ...
       [ 1,  2, 23],
       [ 1,  2, 24]])
```